# Create React App / CRACO -> Webpack Proxy resulting in 504

Tags: webpack, webpack-dev-server

I'm trying to proxy the API calls from my react app to my flask/gnuicorn API server on port 8050.

I use craco.config.ts file to supply a webpack configuration to enable a proxy.

When I call GET /api, I get a error 504 Gateway Timeout. My flask server never logs receipt of any incoming call. If I use curl to run the GET call, I reach the API server OK and everything works.

I set breakpoint via SIGUSR1 to my app and I follow the stack all the way to the proxy to 8050.

```
Client 504 Gateway Timeout
Error occurred while trying to proxy: localhost:3000/api/comp

Webpack/express
  express:router dispatching GET /api/comp +15s
  express:router query  : /api/comp +1ms
  express:router expressInit  : /api/comp +0ms
  express:router handleWebpackInternalMiddleware  : /api/comp +0ms
  express:router compression  : /api/comp +0ms
  express:router trim prefix (/api/comp) from url /api/comp/39.81906745569096%2C%20-86.0677858158628 +0ms
  express:router bound setHeaders /api/comp +0ms
  express:router middleware  : /api/comp +0ms
  express:router handler  : /api/comp +1ms
```

craco.config.ts

```
export = {
    mode: 'development',
    devServer: {
        port: 3000,
        open: true,
        historyApiFallback: true,
        proxy: {
            '/api': {
                target: 'http://localhost:8050',
                secure: false,
                changeOrigin: true,
                logLevel: "debug",
                headers: {
                    Connection: 'keep-alive'
                }
            },
        },
    },
};
```

flask_app.py

```
    app.run(
        host="0.0.0.0",
        port=8050,
        debug=True,
    )
```

logs from flask app run:

```
WARNING: This is a development server. Do not use it in a production deployment. Use a production WSGI server instead.
 * Running on all addresses (0.0.0.0)
 * Running on http://127.0.0.1:8050
 * Running on http://192.168.16.204:8050
```

I tried multiple configurations of target and router in the craco.config.ts to no success. I'm sure that the configuration is being picked up OK because I can set breakpoints in the express.js that show that the routing to 8050 is happening.

If I hardcode the call to localhost:8050 in my react app and enable CORS on my API server then all works as expected.

Answer (score 1):

Problem solved. The proxy seems to fail due to some COR-like checking (my guess; I can't explain what it is exactly) on the outbound path of the client.

The following replaces localhost with 0.0.0.0 which works fabulously.

```
export = {
    mode: 'development',
    devServer: {
        port: 3000,
        historyApiFallback: true,
        proxy: {
            '/api': {
                target: 'http://0.0.0.0:8050',
            },
        },
    },
};
```

Comment: Thanks for sharing your update, this exact issue started happening to a CRA app I'm building with CRACO providing proxy support, and your suggested fix works.

Comment: It would be good to better understand the root cause as I feel like 'http://localhost:xxxx' should work as intended. I recently updated to node 18 for the local environment and the issue started happening.